# center menu items fallback when flexbox is not available

Tags: html, css

The code I have will display space out the menu items with the available and center the items both horizontally and vertically in each item.

This is achieved with the wrapper for the menu items:

```
.gel-layout {
    list-style: none;
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: -8px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    letter-spacing: -0.31em;
    text-rendering: optimizespeed;
}

.gel-layout--middle {
    align-items: center;
}
```

And on each item:

```
.gel-layout__item {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
}

.gel-layout--fit > .gel-layout__item {
    width: auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.gel-layout--equal > .gel-layout__item {
    display: flex;
}

.gel-layout--middle > .gel-layout__item {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the same effect for browsers that do not support flexbox?

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 100%;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
}

body {
  font-size: 160%;
  margin: 0;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


/* autoprefixer: off */


/**
     * Grid containing element
     */

a {
  color: #fff;
}

path {
  fill: #ffffff;
}

.menu__container:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.menu__container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu__container ul li a {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.gel-wrap {
  max-width: 1008px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 25em) {
  .gel-wrap {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 80em) {
  .gel-wrap {
    max-width: 1280px;
  }
}


/**
     * A grid row
     */

.gel-layout {
  list-style: none;
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: left;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: -8px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  letter-spacing: -0.31em;
  text-rendering: optimizespeed;
}

@media (min-width: 37.5em) {
  .gel-layout {
    margin-left: -16px;
  }
}

.opera-only:-o-prefocus,
.gel-layout {
  word-spacing: -0.43em;
}


/**
     * A single grid item
     */

.gel-layout__item {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 37.5em) {
  .gel-layout__item {
    padding-left: 16px;
  }
}


/**
     * Layouts with no gutters.
     */

.gel-layout--flush {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.gel-layout--flush>.gel-layout__item {
  padding-left: 0;
}


/**
     * Reversed rendered order of layout items, e.g. items 1, 2, 3, 4 in your
     * markup will display in order 4, 3, 2, 1 on your page
     */

.gel-layout--rev {
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.no-flexbox .gel-layout--rev {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: left;
}

.no-flexbox .gel-layout--rev>.gel-layout__item {
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: left;
}


/**
     * Align layout items to the vertical centers of each other
     */

.gel-layout--middle {
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-grid-row-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gel-layout--middle>.gel-layout__item {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


.gel-layout--center {
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gel-layout--auto>.gel-layout__item {
  width: auto;
}


.gel-layout--no-flex {
  min-width: 100%;
}

.gel-layout--no-flex,
.gel-layout--no-flex>.gel-layout__item {
  display: block;
  display: inline-block;
}


.gel-layout--equal>.gel-layout__item {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}


/**
         * Allow items to devide the space equally between the number of items
         */

.gel-layout--fit>.gel-layout__item {
  width: auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}


/**
         * Align a single grid item to the top
         */

.gel-layout__item--top {
  -webkit-align-self: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-item-align: start;
  align-self: flex-start;
}


/**
         * Align a single grid item to the center
         */

.gel-layout__item--center {
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}


/**
         * Align a single grid item to the bottom
         */

.gel-layout__item--bottom {
  -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.gel-layout--middle {
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-grid-row-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>Cutting-Edge Solutions (Scotland)</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <header role="banner" aria-label="Cutting-Edge Solutions (Scotalnd)">
      <nav class="menu__container">
        <div class="gel-wrap">
          <div class="gel-layout gel-layout--middle gel-layout--equal gel-layout--fit">
            <div class="gel-layout__item      ">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
                  <path d="M20 0 L40 20 L20 40 L0 20"></path>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="gel-layout__item      "><a href="/">Home</a></div>
            <div class="gel-layout__item      "><a href="/oss">OSS</a></div>
            <div class="gel-layout__item      "><a href="/blog">Blog</a></div>
            <div class="gel-layout__item      "><a href="/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="gel-wrap">
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS Tables can do that:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 100%;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
}

body {
  font-size: 160%;
  margin: 0;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


/* autoprefixer: off */


/**
     * Grid containing element
     */

a {
  color: #fff;
}

path {
  fill: #ffffff;
}

.menu__container:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.menu__container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu__container ul li a {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.gel-wrap {
  max-width: 1008px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 25em) {
  .gel-wrap {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 80em) {
  .gel-wrap {
    max-width: 1280px;
  }
}


/**
     * A grid row
     */

.gel-layout {
  list-style: none;
  direction: ltr;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  letter-spacing: -0.31em;
  text-rendering: optimizespeed;
}

.gel-layout__item {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu__container">
  <div class="gel-wrap">
    <div class="gel-layout gel-layout--middle gel-layout--equal gel-layout--fit">
      <div class="gel-layout__item      ">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
                  <path d="M20 0 L40 20 L20 40 L0 20"></path>
                </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="gel-layout__item      "><a href="/">Home</a></div>
      <div class="gel-layout__item      "><a href="/oss">OSS</a></div>
      <div class="gel-layout__item      "><a href="/blog">Blog</a></div>
      <div class="gel-layout__item      "><a href="/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```